# How to get any file from android phone

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get any file from an android phone and send it to a server.

This is my code to pick any file from the phone:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_FILE);`
```

Then, I get all informations of this file on activity result:

```
String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(AttachmentsActivity.this, selectedImageUri, proj, null, null, null);
Cursor cursorPath = loader.loadInBackground();
if (cursorPath != null) {
    int column_index = cursorPath.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursorPath.moveToFirst();
    mFilePath = cursorPath.getString(column_index);
    cursorPath.close();
}

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, null, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    Log.i("Ecandidat", "cursor not null");
    String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
    int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);

    String size = "unknown";
    if (!cursor.isNull(sizeIndex))
        size = cursor.getString(sizeIndex);
    if (mFilePath == null) {
        mFilePath = selectedImageUri.getPath();
        mFilePath = mFilePath.substring(0, mFilePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        mFilePath += displayName;
    }
    int sizeInt = Integer.parseInt(size);
    double sizeFloat = sizeInt;
    sizeFloat /= 1048576;
    DecimalFormat dff = new DecimalFormat(".##");
    size = dff.format(sizeFloat);
    if (sizeFloat < 1)
        size = "0" + size;
    mCurrentAttachment = new Attachment(-1, displayName, selectedImageUri.getPath(), mCommentPieceEditText.getText().toString(), mMode, sizeInt, false);
    mAttachmentSizeTextView.setText(size + " MB");
    mAttachmentNameTextView.setText(displayName);
    findViewById(R.id.attachmentInfosLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.attachmentDeleteLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cursor.close();

}
```

Sorry for this code, I tried many things before posted this message.

So, when i would send the file to the server, i would like create a File from mFilePath string.

And file.exists() returns always false.

This is my code to create a file from the path.

```
if (mCurrentAttachment == null || mFilePath == null)
    return;

File sourceFile = new File(mFilePath);
Log.i("Ecandidat", "upload file: " + mFilePath);

if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
    Toast.makeText(AttachmentsActivity.this, "file doesen't exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("Ecandidat", "Source File not exist :" + mFilePath);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(AttachmentsActivity.this, "file exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I don't understand why file.exists returns false because i found this code on many topics and it works many people but don't works for me.

My manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If anyone has any idea....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get all informations of this file on activity result

At best, that code will work only if you get a `Uri` from the `MediaStore`. There are **many** ways that you will get a `Uri` that is not from the `MediaStore`.

> i would like create a File from mFilePath string.

A `Uri` does not necessarily point to a file, let alone one for which you can find a path, let alone one for which you can access.

> i found this code on many topics and it works many people

It works for nobody on modern versions of Android.

Use the `Uri` properly:

- Use `DocumentFile` to get at information such as the size of the content
- Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get a stream on the content itself

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i'll test that

Answer (score 0):

It works when i take a file from the phone but when i take a photo by the camera, file.isFile returns false. Do you know why ?

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    mFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(AttachmentsActivity.this, selectedImageUri);

    if (mFile.exists() && mFile.isFile()) {
        mCurrentAttachment = new Attachment(-1, mFile.getName(), "", mCommentPieceEditText.getText().toString(), mMode, mFile.length(), false);
        mAttachmentSizeTextView.setText(mCurrentAttachment.getSize() + " KB");
        mAttachmentNameTextView.setText(mCurrentAttachment.getName());
        findViewById(R.id.attachmentInfosLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.attachmentDeleteLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

This is my code. mFile is a DocumentFile.

Thanks